# How can I remove the JW Player text from the video?

Tags: wordpress

I use "JW Player 6 Plugin for Wordpress" Plugin in my wordpress site.
How can I remove the "JW Player" text from the video[image]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JW Player Free edition is for non-commercial sites only and it includes that watermark.

Maybe you should consider getting some other Video player that is free like [MedieElements.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/).

You can get MedieElements.js and some other players by installing [Hana Flv Player](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hana-flv-player/) plugin.